# Hierarchical tree in flex through json

Tags: apache-flex

hi i have to create Hierarchical tree in flex through json. Please let me know if there is any type of help

Answer (score 1):

How about the Flex Tree control?  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Tree.html